# copying between interleaved openGL Vertex Buffer Objects

Tags: c++, opengl, copy, vbo

using opengl 3.3, radeon 3870HD, c++..

I got question about interleaved arrays of data. I got in my application structure in vector, which is send as data to buffer object. Something like this:

```
struct data{
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
};

std::vector<data> datVec;
...
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(data)*datVec.size(), &datVec[0], GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
```

this is ok I use this thing very often. But what I create is interleaved array so data are like:

```
a1,b1,c1,a2,b2,c2,a3,b3,c3
```

Now I send this thing down for processing in GPU and with transform feedback I read back into buffer for example b variables. So it looks like:

```
bU1, bU2, bU3
```

I'd like to copy updated values into interleaved buffer, can this be done with some single command like glCopyBufferSubData? This one isn't suitable as it only takes offset and size not stride (probably it's something like memcpy in c++)... The result should look like:

```
a1, bU1, c1, a2, bU2, c2, a3, bU3, c3
```

If not is there better approach than these 2 mine?

1. map updated buffer, copy values into temp storage in app, unmap updated, map data buffer and itterating through it set new values
2. separate buffers on constant buffer and variable buffer. constant will stay same over time but using glCopyBufferSubData the variable one can be updated in single call..

Thanks

Comment: I'd keep the updated data separate as your 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would separate the dynamic part with a static one (your point 2).

If you still want to keep them interleaved into a single buffer, and you have some spare video memory, you can do the following:

1. Copy the original interleaved array into a backup one. This requires memory for all components rather than only dynamic ones, how it was originally.
2. Transform Feedback into the original interleaved, carrying the static values unchanged.

Comment: Well I got plenty of memory but in fact I want to use as much as I need and nothing more... trying to get good habits you know :) But now there are 2 answers with 2 different recommendations.. So how big could be difference in performance? Because having 2 buffers instead of 1 for everything, code can get messy and if there's not really big performance hit mapping seems like better solution. So why would you use separate buffers ?

Comment: Simple as that - mapping requires transferring your data through the system bus into RAM and back into VRAM, not to mention CPU time spent on copying. TF, on the other hand, does everything you need on GPU without leaving VRAM, so I would bet on it :)

Comment: yes as I mentioned in other comment I thought that mapping is done within VRAM and not that whole thing gets into local RAM.. Well now it will need some good naming to keep track of what is what but thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[glMapBuffer](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glMapBuffer.xml) seems like a better solution for what you are doing.

The basic idea, from what I can tell, is to map the buffer into your address space, and then update the buffer manually using your own update method (iterative loop likely).

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer_id);
void *buffer = glMapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_WRITE_ONLY);

if (buffer == NULL)
  //Handle Error, usually means lack of virtual memory

for (int i = 1; i < bufferLen; i += stride /* 3, in this case */)
  buffer[i] = newValue;

glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
```

Comment: well so no one step function... btw what about mapping 2 buffers at same time? because that's just writing but in fact there is read/write operation going on.. use some storage in client memory or is it possible to do fully server side

Comment: So far as I can tell, glMapBuffer only allows mapping the buffer into client memory, and only a single buffer... per type.  You can map multiple buffers of different types, from the look of it.

Comment: Actually, you may be able to map multiple buffers by binding different buffers between calls to `glMapBuffer` and not calling `glUnmapBuffer` until after all of them have been mapped / updated.

Comment: yes there are 2 buffers prepared for copy operation GL_COPY_READ(WRITE)_BUFFER I think.. I was just curious if there could be 2 mapped buffers at same time. But you said something more "mapping the buffer into client memory".. deos that mean whole buffer gets copied into client memory? (I thought that returned pointer is pointing to graphic memory...)

Comment: I believe it just maps your client virtual address space to graphics card memory, so there is no copy.

Comment: Ok well I'm going to test it as noone knows for sure.. will need some really big buffers but I hope system will stand together after it..

Comment: Well couldn't find much better monitor than process explorer but it looks like it's actually loading something somewhere.. with 20mb of data after bufferData it was 40 and after mapping 60.. not sure about 200mb of data.. I could send data to VRAM, mapped, but on calling Unmap app crashed realating to memory thing.. looks like this isn't way..